# How to Pause a Recording that is currently being recorded using getusermedia?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I Am using the getusermedia and webaudioAPI to record a audio from user iam able to record and save the recorded data to server then i tried to pause/resume recording the below code is what i have tried but its showing the following error.

```
1>InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable at function resumeRecording()
```

```js
var recordButton, stopButton, recorder;


window.onload = function () {

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true
    })
    .then(function (stream) {
        if (recorder == null) {
            recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', onRecordingReady);
        }

        }).catch(function (err) {
            alert(err)
        });;

};


function startRecording() {
  //  recordButton.disabled = true;
    //  stopButton.disabled = false;
    recorder.start();

}

function stopRecording() {
   // recordButton.disabled = false;
  //  stopButton.disabled = true;
    recorder.stop();


}

function pauseRecording()
{
    if (recorder.recording) {
        recorder.stop();

    }
}
function resumeRecording()
{

        recorder.start();

}
```

button click:

```
   $(document).on('click','.btnPause',function(){

            x(this.title);
            $(this).html('Resume');
            $(this).removeClass('btnPause');
            $(this).addClass('btnResume');
            pauseRecording();
            return false;

        });
        $(document).on('click','.btnResume',function(){
            x(this.title);
            $(this).html('Resume');
            $(this).removeClass('btnResume');
            $(this).addClass('btnPause');
            resumeRecording();      
            return false;
        });
```

How can i achieve this ? Need your help and i will be thankful  if anyone can get me through this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i overcome the situation the pause and resume was not available previously for mediarecorderAPI but now the **MediaRecorder.Pause()** and **MediaRecorder.Resume()** functions can be used for *pause and resume*.

```
 $(document).on('click','.btnPause',function(){


       x(this.title);
        if (recorder.state === "recording") {

            recorder.pause();
            $(this).html('Resume');
          //  Console.log(recorder.state);
            // recording paused
        } else if (recorder.state === "paused") {
            $(this).html('Pause');
            recorder.resume();
            // resume recording
        }
        return false;

    });
```